# login form and payment not working version 1.9.1

Tags: magento, payment, magento-1.9.1

I use to have version 1.7.  Then I have updated it with version 1.9.1( full release) from admin panel. After few tweaks the website was live again. But now i have issue of loging and payment system not working both paypal and sagepay.

After reading somewhere then i downloaded and reinstalled this version again manually by using ftp but both errors below still same

I m new to magento and this site is done by other company before. I got two major issue at the minute

1) Everytime i login it goes to login page without any error message on the page.

2) every time i try to place an order (step 6 of payment) it stucks on /checkout/onepage/ and it shows not error message at all but just stays on same page /checkout/onepage/.

Can anyone have an idea whats going wrong. Realy stuck from yesterday. Thanks

Comment: any errors in var/exception?

Comment: please check the tmp  & var/session folder permission in your magento setup....hope this help

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the issue with questions are that you're missing form keys and other modifications needed for a 1.7 + upgrade. Form keys are an addition since 1.8 and if you're theme isn't upgraded it will cause this issue. To diagnose, begin by changing your package to "base" delete the var/cache and var/session directories and then begin the checkout process. I know you're site will be missing all css, etc, but this will significantly narrow down the problem.   If you can make it through successfully without any issues.  You have determined your problem is related to the theme being compatible with new version of Magento.  Let me know what happens here and I will post back with next steps